# Rails Omniauth Facebook login redirects to sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

for some reason my Omniauth Facebook login is redirecting to /users/sign_up#*=* - but otherwise appears to be working. I have this in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

I have this in application.html.erb:

```
 <%= link_to "", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :origin=>"root_url") %> 
                      <%= link_to(image_tag("FB-Login.png"),    
 user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :origin=>"root_url", class:"mycss") %>
```

I have this in application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      Rails.logger.level = 0 
      logger.debug "after_sign_in_path_for"
          logger.debug "Session: #{@session.inspect}"
      logger.debug "omniauth.origin: #{omniauth.origin}"
          logger.debug "root_url: #{root_url}"
    ##  if request.env['omniauth.origin']
##    request.env['omniauth.origin']
      request.env['omniauth.origin'] || root_url
  end
```

Funny thing is the log statements are not showing in the heroku logs - looks like after_sign_in_path_for is not called ??

Any help appreciated,
Slavko

Comment: class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

    def facebook
 omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
         @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

         Rails.logger.level = 0 
      logger.debug "Session: #{@session.inspect}"
   logger.debug "USer: #{@user.inspect}"
   logger.debug "Omniauth: #{@omniauth.inspect}

      And Logger output:

      Omniauth: nil
      Session: nil

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that user already exist?

Try to check user existence prior to persistence:

```
def facebook
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if @user
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```